# Setting a Row as Selected Based off of NSUserDefaults Value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I'm currently working on a view where a player can choose a character to play with. I have a tableView where each row represents a character. Inside each row is a button that a player taps to select that respective character. The first time a user loads it, only one character is available (first row) and I do the following in viewDidLoad:

```
//If not selected character exists set it to the default character
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Current Character"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"Current Character"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
NSLog(@"Value: %d", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Current Character"]);
```

By default all of the buttons in each row are hidden revealing a lock image behind it. So I do the following in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
//CHECK FOR UNLOCKED ITEMS
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0: {
        //Always show since it will always be available
        cell.playerButton.hidden = NO;
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"item2Unlocked"]) {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = NO;
        } else {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = YES;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"item3Unlocked"]) {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = NO;
        } else {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = YES;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"item4Unlocked"]) {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = NO;
        } else {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = YES;
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```

Everything is working great so far. **The problem that I'm facing is figuring out how to update the button in the correct row to a selected state.** I've tried doing the following, but it ends up updating more than one button:

```
//CHECK FOR UNLOCKED ITEMS
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0: {
        cell.playerButton.hidden = NO;
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Current Character"] == 0) {
            cell.playerButton.selected = YES;
        } else {
            cell.playerButton.selected = NO;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"item1Unlocked"]) {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = NO;
            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Current Character"] == 1) {
                cell.playerButton.selected = YES;
            } else {
                cell.playerButton.selected = NO;
            }
        } else {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = YES;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"item2Unlocked"]) {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = NO;
            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Current Character"] == 2) {
                cell.playerButton.selected = YES;
            } else {
                cell.playerButton.selected = NO;
            }
        } else {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = YES;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"item3Unlocked"]) {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = NO;
            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Current Character"] == 3) {
                cell.playerButton.selected = YES;
            } else {
                cell.playerButton.selected = NO;
            }
        } else {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = YES;
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```

What's wrong here?

## UPDATE

Doing the following, the selected state finally worked:

```
//CHECK FOR UNLOCKED ITEMS
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0: {
        cell.playerButton.hidden = NO;
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Current Character"] == 0) {
            cell.playerButton.selected = YES;
            NSLog(@"Character is selected.");
        } else {
            cell.playerButton.selected = NO;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"item1Unlocked"]) {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = NO;
            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Current Character"] == 1) {
                cell.playerButton.selected = YES;
                NSLog(@"Character B is selected.");
            } else {
                cell.playerButton.selected = NO;
            }
        } else {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = YES;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"item3Unlocked"]) {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = NO;
            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Current Character"] == 2) {
                cell.playerButton.selected = YES;
                NSLog(@"character C is selected.");
            } else {
                cell.playerButton.selected = NO;
            }
        } else {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = YES;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"item4Unlocked"]) {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = NO;
            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Current Character"] == 3) {
                cell.playerButton.selected = YES;
                NSLog(@"Character D is selected.");
            } else {
                cell.playerButton.selected = NO;
            }
        } else {
            cell.playerButton.hidden = YES;
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```

However how can I disable the button or user interaction if button is selected?

Comment: this happened because you have @"Current Character" in UserDefault with values 2,3,4. You should exclude that.

Comment: Thanks for your time @NeverBe but could you be a bit more detailed, sorry.

Comment: too much if conditions, can you make it simple ?

Comment: you have more then one button selected @user1886754 ? show didSelectRowAtIndexPath method also.

Comment: @hemantchittora That's the problem I don't know if there's a better way to simplify this.

Comment: @NeverBe Since the cell itself isn't selectable I'm not using didSelectRowAtIndexPath, instead I'm setting the tag of each row to its respective indexpath.row and when the button is hit it calls another method which contains a switch statement that responds accordingly to the sender.

Comment: @user1886754 that is the problem. Try to reload whole table after button has pressed

Comment: here both piece of code is from your cellForRowAtIndexPath method ?

Comment: [tableView reload] is that useful??

Comment: To simplify the code, maybe you should move the part where you set the selected state above the `switch` statement and check `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Current Character"]` with `indexPath.row`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the same thing and is a lot simpler

```
//CHECK FOR UNLOCKED ITEMS
   int currentCharacter=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Current Character"];
   BOOL unlocked=NO;

   if (indexPath.row == 0)
   {
       unlocked=YES;        // Character 0 is always unlocked
   }
   else {
     unlocked=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@item%dUnlocked",indexPath.row]]
   }

   if (unlocked)
   {
      cell.playerButton.hidden=NO;
      if (indexPath.row == currentCharacter)
      {
          cell.playerButton.selected=YES;
          cell.playerButton.enabled=NO;      //Cannot select if already selected
      }
      else
      {
          cell.playerButton.selected=NO;
          cell.playerButton.enabled=YES;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      cell.playerButton.hidden=YES;
   }
```